# UITableView Expanding Sections takes too much time

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, uitableview, grand-central-dispatch

I have the expandable `UITableView` subclass. When a user clicks on a header then the table view removes all rows and only shows the section headers. If the user clicks again - all rows will be shown. The problem is: when the rows and sections counts become too large - table view is freezing and crash the user experience. I've tried to add each section in a different thread but still failed. The next code I've made is crashing when inserting rows with

> he number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (23) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (0), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

But I never reload my table view don't change the counts in data source methods.
The code for expanding

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

                for (int sec = 0; sec < [self.myCustomTableViewDataSource numberOfSectionsInTableView:self]; sec++) {
//                    NSString *threadNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"inserting_thread_%tu", sec];
//                    dispatch_queue_t customQueue = dispatch_queue_create([threadNumber UTF8String], 0);
//
//                    dispatch_sync(customQueue, ^{
//
//                    });

                    [self.contractedSections removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:sec]];

                    NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray new];


                    for (int i = 0; i < [self.myCustomTableViewDataSource resizableTableView:self numberOfRowsInSection:sec]; i++) {
                        [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:sec]];
                    }
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        [self insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
                    });
                }
            });
```

Comment: Use UIButton action and reload tableView instead of dispatch and for loop  .

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy Oh, really, forgot about this easy solution. Double thanks!

Comment: I have posted answer for more details and for any other person who have doubt like you can read the answer and follow the best coding coding style. If you still have doubt's , how to achieve the result of your question then you can ask. Hope you up vote the answer for other developers. Thanks.